# Spring controller URL parameter handling with generics: ClassCastException

Tags: spring, generics, spring-mvc, controller, classcastexception

Spring is behaving strange... This is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public void search(SearchDTO dto) {
    System.out.println(dto.testa.contains);
    System.out.println(dto.testa.contains.getClass());
    System.out.println(dto.testb.contains);
    System.out.println(dto.testb.contains.getClass());
}
```

SearchDTO.java:

```
public class SearchDTO {    
    public UUIDListSearchDTO testa;
    public UUIDListSearchDTO getTesta() { return testa; }
    public void setTesta(UUIDListSearchDTO testa) { this.testa = testa; }

    public ListSearchDTO<UUID> testb;
    public ListSearchDTO<UUID> getTestb() { return testb; }
    public void setTestb(ListSearchDTO<UUID> testb) { this.testb = testb; }
}
```

ListSearchDTO.java:

```
public class ListSearchDTO<C> {

    public C contains;
    public C getContains() { return contains; }
    public void setContains(C contains) { this.contains = contains; }

}
```

UUIDListSearchDTO.java:

```
public class UUIDListSearchDTO extends ListSearchDTO<UUID> {

}
```

Now I call the following URL:

`GET http://localhost:8080/myApp/myController?testa.contains=11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111&testb.contains=11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111`

The output I get:

```
11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111
class java.util.UUID
11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.UUID
```

**Why does this happen?**

Btw: I'm using Spring 4.0.0.M3, maybe someone can test it with Spring 3?

---

### STACK TRACE:

I've set debug level to `trace` for the whole application.

http://pastebin.com/UuiUrscq

(Exception happens at line 72: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.UUID`)

Request URL: `http://localhost:8080/copilot/assets?foreignKeys.contains=11112222-3333-4444-5555-66667777`

Comment: Can you do some debugging? Try and check the DTO right before any of the `sysout`s and see what it holds. Is it a proxy? This error should've occurred much sooner.

Comment: I'll set my whole loggin to TRACE, and share the results

Comment: added stack trace: http://pastebin.com/UuiUrscq